# Is it possible to receive SMS text messages in iPad Air?

Tags: ipad

iPad Air has SIM card inside.

Can I receive SMS messages with it?

My mobile provider sends control information by SMS messages, which I can't receive apparently.

Comment: I think this is only possible when you have an iPhone running iOS 8+ and that you are signed in with the same Apple ID on the iPhone and iPad

Comment: Do you have an iPhone? [here](http://www.ianswerguy.com/sms-text-messages-on-an-ipad/) are the instructions very well explained.